# taking account another value in different column with the same value in the main column

Tags: sql

| id | year |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2010 |
| 2 | 2010 |
| 1 | 2009 |
| 3 | 2010 |

I'm trying to output 2 and 3 with the SQL query by using the logic in the year. it outputs id who only has a year equals to 2010, but not 2009 if it ever has it. id 1 is not in the output because it has 2009 once in the table. I wonder how to exeCute this with SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

If you want ids where the minimum year is 2010, you can use `group by` and `having`:

```
select id
from t
group by id
having min(year) = 2010;
```

EDIT:

Based on the comment, you can be more specific.  If you want *only* 2010, then:

```
having min(year) = max(year) and min(year) = 2010
```

Comment: is there anyway if i only want 2010, but not id which has 2009? (in this case, id 1 which has both is out)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery:

```
Select * from table 
where id not in 
    (select id from table where year = 2009)
```